# Linked List strange behavior

Tags: c, pointers, structure, singly-linked-list

I don't know how to ask this question, so I present it with an example. I hope you understand it.
Here's the structure node:

```
typedef struct NODE {
    struct NODE *link;
    int data;
} SList;
```

Suppose I use the `appendList(Node *list, int data);` [you can use your own also] function to insert the node into a list like this:

```
int main() {
   SList *list1 = NULL;
   // append like this: 1, 2, 3
   list1 = appendList(list1, 1);
   list1 = appendList(list1, 2);
   list1 = appendList(list1, 3);
   SList *list2 = list1;  

   // Here starts the confusing part (atleast for me)
   int i = 1;
   while(i--) {
    list1 = list1->link;
   }
   // Now list1 == list1->link;
   list1 = NULL;   // This is the point of confusion
   printf("%d", list2->link->link->data);     // Return 3

}
```

Now my question is when I assign `NULL` to `list1->link` after while loop then printing the value of `list2->link->link->data` cause exit failure, but when it assign to `list1` (which after while loop becomes `list1->link`) then `printf()` safely print the value.  Why?

Comment: It is only a pointer. You set it to NULL, but you did not do anything to the object where it pointed to. Burning the address does not burn the house.

Comment: @wildplasser So when I assign the NULL to list1, then is it assign to `list1->link` or simply `list1`

Comment: Neither. You _only_ change the value of the pointer (set it to NULL). Th object where it pointed to is **not affected**. (-> the linked list is still the same. )

Comment: But I changed it after while loop. Is `while` loop doesn't increment the pointer

Comment: The printf() uses the list2 pointer, which you copied before list1 started moving.

Comment: Yes, but when I assign NULL to `list1->link` then why list2 pointer doesn't print the value of `list2->link->link` but printing `list2->link` value

Comment: Because at that point list->link refers to one of the actial nodes (the second). In that case you would alter one of the actual objects. BTW: it is very confusing (at least to me) to put the crucial code in the text outside of the code block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exit failure is because when you assign `NULL` to `list1->link`, after while loop then the value of `list2->link->link` become is `NULL` and you are trying to printf `NULL->data`. 
Whereas if you set `list1 = NULL` it doesn't corrupt you linked-list and `list2->link->link` points to third/last node with data value 3.
Below is my explanation with ascii-diagrams:

Before while loop, you list is something like this:

**Step-1**

```
Before while loop  

+---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 1 |--->| 2 |--->| 3 |---+
+---+    +---+    +---+   |                                
 ^                       null  
 |                
list1
list2 = list1;

Both `list2`, `list1` are pointing to first node
```

the `while(--i)` loop runs for single time because `i = 1`. In while loop body, you updates `list1` to point to next node and after while loop it becomes as below:

**Step-2**

```
After: list1 = list1->link; in while-loop

+---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 1 |--->| 2 |--->| 3 |---+
+---+    +---+    +---+   |                                
 ^         ^             null  
 |         |             
list2     list1
```

**Step-3a**

Case-1: if you set `list1->link` to NULL: then your list becomes:

```
After: list1->link = NULL

+---+    +---+          +---+                               
| 1 |--->| 2 |---+      | 3 |---+
+---+    +---+   |      +---+   |                                
 ^         ^     null          null  
 |         |             
list2     list1

A bad think, You do not have any variable pointing to node with value `3`
```

Now understand what is `list2->link->link->data`

`list2->link` points to node `2`. And next of node with value `2` is null after the assignment statment. So `` `ist2->link->link `` value is NULL.
And by printing `list2->link->link->data`  you are actually printing `NULL->data` that is wrong! reason of your program crash.

**Step-3b**,

This is Case-2: if  `NULL` is assigned to `list` then things become like below shown in diagram:

```
After set: list1 = NULL 

+---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 1 |--->| 2 |--->| 3 |---+
+---+    +---+    +---+   |                                
 ^                      null  
 |                      
list2     list1---> NULL

1.  Linked-List is correct state. 
2.  Because list1 is assigned NULL, its just shown that it pointing to NULL
3.  Now, list1 not pointing any node in lined-list 
4.  Whereas we can still access linked-list using  variable `list2`.
```

And `printf("%d", list2->link->link->data);` outputs: `3`, to understand this look below

```
+---+    +---+    +---+                               
| 1 |--->| 2 |--->| 3 |---+
+---+    +---+    +---+   |
 ^         ^        ^     null
 |         |        |
 |         |        list2->link->link     
list2     list2->link
```

Comment: Nice drawings. BTW: I don't like the `suppose` section, because this is the thing that **does not** happen (but the OP erroneously _thinks_ it happens)

Comment: Ok, But when I set it to `list1 = NULL`, after while loop then what happens?

Comment: @ashish2expert I was editing the answer, check updated answer

Comment: @wildplasser this is what I mean to say, (I have poor english so please check again if I am wrong somewhere as I updated my answer)

Comment: No sorry, you are correct. I missed the extra piece of code below the code block.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks to like my drawings, you may also like [this](http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw)

Comment: @Grijesh But after I set `list1 = NULL`, then why list2->link->link doesn' break

Comment: @wildplasser :) :) I like ask arts, I have share the link in my profile page.

Comment: I know the step-3b part-2 but can't understand part-1. I mean, where's the arrow pointing to list1

Comment: @ashish2expert not `list1` or `list2` are not actual nodes not they points to nodes

Comment: @ashish2expert ok added some points in diagram in which you have doubts.